# configuring worklight with eclipse

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

[image]

I'm configuring my eclipse with the worklight with [this steps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/studio.html)  while doing that i'm getting the above error as shown in the image.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Worklight supported versions of Eclipse are: Eclipse Juno v4.2.2 (SR2), Eclipse Kepler v4.3.1 (SR1), Eclipse Classic v4.2.2 and Eclipse Classic v4.3.1.

Comment: @ravidor i tried with Juno v4.2.2 and Kepler v4.3.1 both are giving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Worklight is pretty specific to which editions and versions of eclipse are known to work. Running with other editions or versions can lead to unpredictable results. For the current version of IBM Worklight Studio (v6.2), which is on Eclipse Marketplace, double check to ensure you have:

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Juno SR2 (4.2.2), Kepler SR1 (4.3.1), Kepler SR2 (4.3.2), or Luna R (4.4).

as described in the Developer Edition [overview](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/index.html). Also check the other system requirements listed there.

2) You cannot upgrade to Worklight Studio V6.2 from an earlier version of Worklight Developer Edition.

3) Google "MD5 Hash Eclipse". There are lots of suggestions (make sure you're running eclipse as administrator, check your firewall, check your java version, etc.)

4) Could be a corrupted download by eclipse. Try downloading the IBM Worklight Studio 6.2 [zip file](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_eclipse_6.2.0.0.zip) and installing it as a local archive within Eclipse.

Comment: With the zip file i have configured the eclipse with worklight.Thanks

Comment: @barbara "File not found" in http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_eclipse_6.2.0.0.zip you tagged in zip file link

Answer (score 0):

I believe these are network problems. You should try later or in a different network connection.

By the way, I highly recommend to use an Eclipse Java EE version.

Comment: Same problem today also i tried with new download of eclipse .