# IBM Worklight 6.2 SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized:422'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-studio

1) Java version "1.7.0_71" i have installed

2) I download eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1
                     Build id: 20130919-0819 and extracted.

3) I have tried to install worklight6.2 [as said in this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/studio.html) while installing i have faced [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906411/configuring-worklight-with-eclipse) so as per the suggestion in that post i have downloaded worklight6.2 from that site and configured.

4) And then configured ADT plugin with my eclipse.

5) Now i have created a [Hello world app as per the instructions](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/02_01_Creating_your_first_Hybrid_Worklight_application.pdf).

6) Started the server by right click on Worklight development server and  start.

7) Now right click on HelloWorld Run As -> Run on worklight development server.

then i have opened my app in browser and clicked on Preview as common  Resources it but it is giving the following exception in browser:

[image]

i have gone through some of these [links](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=SRVE0777E%3A+Exception+thrown+by+application+class+%27com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized%3A422%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BU1PVMbcEMiCoAOe9oCwAg) but those did not help.

ErrorLog is as follows..

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1/wlp-1.0.4.cl50120131011-1639) on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.7.0_71-b14 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application WorklightConsole has not started in 30.012 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application HelloWorld has not started in 30.027 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator has not started in 30.016 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application WorklightServices has not started in 30.017 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application _analytics has not started in 30.013 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://Harish:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://Harish:10080/worklightadmin/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightServices started in 84.379 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://Harish:10080/_analytics/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _analytics started in 77.031 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://Harish:10080/HelloWorld/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application HelloWorld started in 86.932 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://Harish:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 84.441 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://Harish:10080/worklightconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightConsole started in 87.959 seconds.
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /HelloWorld [project HelloWorld]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /HelloWorld [project HelloWorld]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:435)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: There must be an exception concerning "Read timed out" with a longer stack trace filed in the server log. Can you please post that stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: updated with error log.

Comment: That is not quite what I was expecting. The method verifyServletInitialized throws an exception when it finds a situation caused by an earlier exception, most likely inside ProjectJeeActivator.contextInitialized. Hence I was expecting to find an exception in the log that contains ProjectJeeActivator.contextInitialized in the stack trace.

Comment: Updated all the steps i have followed to install and creating the app in worklight.

Answer (score 0):

Harish,

I have faced similar issues and I know it's frustrating. It's mainly because of the configuration and nothing else.

The key element is to make sure that you have the right eclipse version and have installed the plugins from the market place. I always prefer to download ADT from the Android Developer Site and then install Marketplace and then subsequently install the Worklight plugins. In a way getting the Android configuration done too, we would need it anyway. => This way of installation has helped me configure it well without issues for my peers at workplace.

**I don't remember the exact fix for this issue, but I suggest that you try the following steps:**

1. Make sure that the Java compiler is version 1.7 (Eclipse > Preferences > Compiler > 1.7) and similarly the corresponding JRE version.
2. Increase the Worklight server timeout to 180 seconds if lower. (First enable the server view by Eclipse > Window > Show View > Server > Servers) and then double click on the (Worklight Development Server) which will open up a GUI for it's configuration. In it, you will find Timeouts, increase the start timeout to 180 seconds.
3. Increase the memory allotted to JVM by configuring the jvm.options under Worklight Development Server
   like this -> -Xmx1024m

If these above steps don't help and if you have ample time, then you can start off installing and configuring the way that I have mentioned before.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have re-installed the worklight6.2 studio as you said above but still it is giving the same error

Comment: Did you check the steps such as timeout, jvm etc?

Comment: Yeah all those i have checked they are correct here is the [jvm.options](http://pastie.org/9685186)

Comment: I think you will have to specify in your post your whole configuration such as the eclipse version, java version used, wl version etc. and you will also need the entire stack trace. Check the log file. The current stack trace shows that there are 5 more. Showing all of that will give better insight into the issue.

Comment: Updated all the steps i have followed to install and creating the app in worklight.